# Save coordinates extracted from NMEA log file in a CSV file

Tags: python, export-to-csv, pyserial, nmea

As a beginner in Python I am dealing with a task. The task is developing a program that reads the NMEA log files via a virtual port and:

- printing only "GPGGA" lines
- printing coordinates (lat,lon) from these "GPGGA" lines
- extracting these coordinates in a CSV file
- extracting these coordinates in a KML file

My code is followed:

```
import serial
from pynmea import nmea
import csv

ser=serial.Serial('COM4')
ser.baudrate=4800
f = open('coord_list.csv', 'w+')
print('Waiting for data')
while True:
    try:     
        message = ser.readline().decode() 
        message = message.strip()     
           if '$GPGGA' in message:    
                print(message)
                gpgga = nmea.GPGGA()
                gpgga.parse(message)   
                lat = float(gpgga.latitude)
                lon = float(gpgga.longitude)
                print("Lat %f Long %f" % (lat, lon))
                for i in message:
                    coord_list = []
                    coord = [gpgga.latitude,gpgga.longitude]
                    coord_list.append(coord)
                    f.write(coord_list)
                    f.close()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        raise
ser.close()
```

For the first two bullets a sample output is like:

```
Waiting for data
$GPGGA,170609.941,5335.6665,N,01021.2637,E,1,09,01.1,35.9,M,40.2,M,,*58
Lat 5335.666500 Long 1021.263700
$GPGGA,170610.941,5335.6665,N,01021.2637,W,1,09,01.1,36.0,M,40.2,M,,*5A
```

With this code I got an error:

```
f.write(coord_list)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list
```

I get stuck on saving coordinates under a CSV file. I couldn't figure out how to write a correct code to solve it. Whatever I tried I got another errors or nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is as your error says, that `write` takes string only.
csv format is usually comma seperated.
So you could do like this :

```
f.write("{},{}\n".format(gpgga.latitude, gpgga.longitude))
```

Also you close the file in the loop, but dont open it. So it won't write after first loop.

Comment: @roganjosh yea just noticed. Edited

Comment: I added this line and run it. Now It write only first lat and lon values and writes this first lon value into each following column.

Comment: @fuji_doji edited to add newline. Also close the file after the loop. Not in the loop.