# How to parse data from a NMEA GPS through serial connection in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, serial-port, gps

I am very new to python and I am trying to implement a serial communication with a GPS. There is 4 lines repeating periodically in each sample and I just want those which starts as `GPGGA` to be saved. The GPS is sampling on **5 Hz** as default. I have the code below so far.

```
import serial
import csv

gps = serial.Serial('COM3', 56700, timeout=1)  # opening COM port
gps.flushInput()                    # clears the serial port so there is no data overlaping
gps_bytes = gps.readline()

try: 
    while gps_bytes:
        line = gps.readline()
        if line.find('$GPGGA') != -1:

#else:
    # time, LAT, dir1, LONG, dir2 = line.split(",")[1:5]
            print(line)   

       
        input('Press Enter to stop\n')
except (Exception, KeyboardInterrupt):
        pass
        gps.close()


    #with open("gps_data.csv","a") as f:
     #   writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",")
      #  writer.writerow([time.time(),gps_data])
```

The GPS signal lines are coma separated. Where I want to use only the GPGGA, time (hhmmss.), LON (XX), N, LAT (YY), E line and only need these 3 numeric values (time, LONG, LAT).

`$GPGGA,070611.00, XXXX.XX, N, YYY.Y, E,2,12,0.9,15.147,M,39.586,M,,*50`

`$PNVGBLS,070611.00,,,,,,,N*33`

`$GPRMC,070611.00,A,XXXX.X, N,YYY.Y, E,0.07,0.00,211020,,,D*5E`

`$GPVTG,0.00,T,,,0.07,N,0.13,K,D*70`

`$GPHDT,,T*1B`

What I want, is to open the serial and start firing me data until I hit enter to stop and then save it in a `.csv` file. Can anybody help me with how to do that? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This seems a duplicate question, you just did few hours ago. Right? What do you changed?

Comment: And BTW what it is the problem? Serial? or parsing NMEA? or what? I hope you understand that we are not paid to program for you. We may help, but not more

Comment: For example, may this article be helpful? [Save coordinates extracted from NMEA log file in a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48361774/9014308)